# symfony redirect to a Route url

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following symfony Controller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/login")
     */
    public function loginAction() {
        return $this->render('application/login.html.twig', []);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/signup")
     */
    public function signupAction(Request $request) {
        var_dump($this->generateUrl('/login'));die;
```

However the var_dump tells me:

Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/login" as such route does not exist.

How could i get this to work so i can get the url for login (as seen above)?End result is I would like to forward to login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use route name to generate them, so change your code in

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction() 
{
    return $this->render('application/login.html.twig', []);
}
```

and

```
$this->generateUrl('login');
```